# Primefaces component calendar messes with component wizards next

Tags: primefaces

When i use calendar component inside the wizard component next and back buttons suddenly don't work and my function sledeciKorak is not even called.

When i remove calendar components everything works normally.
This is my sledeciKorak function.

Also I didn't put here my beans and controller but I think that everything is ok with them.

Thanks in advance

```
public String sledeciKorak(FlowEvent event) {

        return event.getNewStep();

}
```

And this is my xhtml code

```
<h:form>
        <p:wizard flowListener="#{kontroler.sledeciKorak}">
        <p:tab id="personal" title="Festivalu">
            <p:panel header="Detalji festivala">
                <p:messages />
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" >

                    <h:outputText value="Naziv: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{kontroler.noviFestival.naziv}" required="true" requiredMessage="Morate uneti naziv" />

                    <h:outputText value="Mesto: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{kontroler.noviFestival.mesto}" required="true" requiredMessage="Morate uneti mesto" />


                    <h:outputText value="Datum pocetka festivala: " />
                    <p:calendar  value="#{kontroler.noviFestival.datumOd}"  required="true" requiredMessage="Morate uneti datum pocetka festivala" /> 

                    <h:outputText value="Datum datum kraja festivala: " />
                    <p:calendar  value="#{kontroler.noviFestival.datumOd}"  required="true" requiredMessage="Morate uneti datum kraja festivala" /> 


                    <h:outputText value="Opis: " />
                    <p:inputTextarea rows="4" cols="50" value="#{kontroler.noviFestival.opis}" required="true" requiredMessage="Morate uneti opis festivala" />

                    <h:outputText value="Maksimalan broj karta za rezervaciju: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{kontroler.noviFestival.maxBrRez}" required="true" requiredMessage="Morate uneti maksimalan broj karta za rezervisanje" />

                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab id="address" title="Projekcije festivala">
            <p:panel header="Pravljenje projekcije na festivalu">

                <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputText value="Izabrati film: " />
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{kontroler.imeFilma}">
                        <f:selectItems  value="#{kontroler.sviOpisiFilmova}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>



                    <h:outputText value="Izabrati lokaciju: " />
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{kontroler.imeLokacije}">
                        <f:selectItems  value="#{kontroler.sviOpisiLokacija}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <h:outputText value="Sala: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{kontroler.trenutnaProjekcija.sala}" required="true" requiredMessage="Morate uneti salu" />

                    <h:outputText value="Broj karta: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{kontroler.trenutnaProjekcija.brSlobodnihKarta}" required="true" requiredMessage="Morate uneti broj karta" />

                    <h:outputText value="Cena karte: " />
                    <p:inputText value="#{kontroler.trenutnaProjekcija.cenaKarte}" required="true" requiredMessage="Morate uneti cenu karte" />

                </p:panelGrid>

            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>
    </p:wizard>
    </h:form>
```